# Can't fix my wordpress jQuery loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use this code snippet: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/8/)

```
    <html>
<body>
    <input id="edValue" type="text" onKeyPress="edValueKeyPress()" onKeyUp="edValueKeyPress()"><br>
    <span id="lblValue">The text box contains: </span>
</body>

<script>
    function edValueKeyPress()
    {
        var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
        var s = edValue.value;

        var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
        lblValue.innerText = "The text box contains: "+s;

        //var s = $("#edValue").val();
        //$("#lblValue").text(s);    
    }
</script>    

</html>
```

**On That page:** [Link](http://landpage.gezerweb.com/%D7%93%D7%A3-%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9/)

It doesn't work and it seems to known wordpress jquery loading problem, so i tried every other fix i found for that and nothing works, if someone can try looking on my page source code and fint out any idea why isn't that working it would be very appreciated!

**Thanks!**

Ben

Comment: Have you tried no conflict mode?
jQuery("#lblValue").text(s);

Answer (score 3):

If your using WordPress, I recommend writing your script more like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#edValue').keypress(function(){
        edValue = jQuery("#edValue").val();
        jQuery("#lblValue").html("The text box contains: " + edValue);
    });
});
```

The reason is that the particular copy of jQuery used in wordpress's `wp_enqueue_script` function is, by default, in [compatibility mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/). Which pretty much means that the usual `$` shortcut for jQuery doesn't work and should be replaced with `jQuery` instead.

And then you can change your HTML to something like this:

```
 <input id="edValue" type="text"><br>
 <span id="lblValue">The text box contains: </span>
```

**[Here is a working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/986/)**

Comment: this is a good answer, however, telling the OP why you recommend that code is very important as well.

Comment: @DrCord agreed, will update accordingly :-)